# VLC won't run DVDs

Tags: vlc, dvd

Just updated to the newest version of Ubuntu and now VLC player won't read DVDs and displays the following message every time I try to play a DVD:

```
Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "/dev/dvd".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///dev/dvd'. Check the log for details.
```

What actions do I need to take?

Comment: Missing details: Which **Ubuntu** version? 32-bit or 64-bit? Have you loaded the optional extras, codecs, DVD handling, etc. ?

Comment: 32 bit, have loaded libdvdread 4.  I am new to running ubunto so I have figured out all the optional extras

Answer (score 2):

**Play DVD's on VLC Ubuntu 13.10:**

1. Make sure your entire os system is up to date with ubuntu software updater.
2. Install vlc:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install vlc
   ```
3. open source alternatives to DRM around DVD's

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
   sudo apt-get install libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4
   sudo apt-get install libavformat-extra-53 libavcodec-extra-53 libdvdread4
   sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
   ```
4. Restart the computer, Run VLC, Right click the screen "Open Media" -> "Open Disc".
5. Select the DVD radio bubble
6. The DVD menu comes up and I can click on the screen to navigate the menus and play the DVD.

Update from 10 years later...

DRM has had its way with unix on Ubuntu, here's a nickel kid, use a better operating system.

Comment: For those using Kubuntu, the restricted extras are different: `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-restricted-extras`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after installing all needed codecs.  I found that I needed to add the symbolic link to the DVD

```
sudo ln -s /dev/sr0 /dev/dvd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try entering these three commands: (to see if any of it is missing)

`sudo apt-get -y install w32codecs ubuntu-restricted-extras`

`sudo apt-get -y install libdvdcss2 libdvdnav4 libdvdread4`

`sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh`

---

**UPDATE**

If you don't already have **Medibuntu** (Ubuntu Media extras), then add that first:

> Add repository
>
> **`sudo wget
>   --output-document=/etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list http://www.medibuntu.org/sources.list.d/$(lsb_release -cs).list &&
>   sudo apt-get --quiet update`**  (all on one line)
>
> Add repository key
>
> **`sudo apt-get --allow-unauthenticated install medibuntu-keyring`**
>
> Update packages
>
> **`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade`**
>
> Update *Software Center* (with new media-apps)
>
> **`sudo update-apt-xapian-index`**  (this may take 40+ seconds)

Comment: Everything else seemed fine but was missing the codecs.  This is the message I got: E: Unable to locate package w32codecs

Comment: Medibuntu repository no longer exists. You have to choose the ubuntu-restricted-extras.

Comment: ***Agreed.*** *Time has moved on.* For a new install of Ubuntu **12.04 LTS** or **13.10** you can just use restricted extra. *There are still issues with **13.10** (or **13.04**), and I should update my answer ..*