# Switched from Win to Ubuntu 12.04 and CD & DVD Drives aren't recognizing media

Tags: 12.04, dvd, codecs

I had an old reliable desktop running WinXP, but after some registry errors caused the system to be unstable I thought I'd give Ubuntu a try. I booted the 12.04 iso from the CD drive and the installation seemed to go smoothly. However, after installing updates and re-booting neither of my optical drives seem to work. One is a TDK CDRW 24/10/40B and the other a Pioneer DVR-105.

output from **sudo lshw | grep cdrom**:

```
   *-cdrom:0 logical name: /dev/cdrom1
*-cdrom:1 logical name: /dev/cdrom
```

output from **sudo lshw**

```
 *-cdrom:0
             description: CD-R/CD-RW writer
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom1
             logical name: /dev/cdrw1
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             capabilities: audio cd-r cd-rw
             configuration: status=nodisc
        *-cdrom:1
             description: DVD writer
             product: DVD-RW  DVR-105
             vendor: PIONEER
             physical id: 0.1.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.1.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr1
             version: 1.33
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

Looking through other posts that dealt with the same problem, I installed libdvdnav4, libdvdcss2, libdvdcss-dev, libdvdread4, gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad and gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly packages. I can see both drives from the Computer window, but neither shows under Devices on the left side of file manager.

I'd appreciate some help if anyone has any suggestions.
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/185587/why-does-dvd-playback-still-not-work-after-installing-libdvdcss2 or http://askubuntu.com/questions/302632/vlc-wont-run-dvds

Answer (score 0):

to find out if the recorder was recognized, type `dmesg | grep "sr0"` in a terminal. You should get a response similar to:

```
[    1.649270] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 40x/40x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.649445] sr 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
```

check mounted non-blank media:
To be sure there it is not mounted execute this in a terminal: mount | grep "/dev/sr"
If the response is blank there is no non-blank media mounted in your media drive. Blank media is not showing up here.

Note:
your drive might be called sr1 or sr2 if you have several; in that case replace sr0 with sr1 in that case (or simply sr to catch them all).

Comment: ,output from `dmesg | grep "sr"`  0.904278] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 204x/40x writer cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    0.904472] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[    0.904644] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
[    0.917069] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 32x/32x writer cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    0.917260] sr 1:0:1:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that nothing happens from `mount | grep "/dev/sr"` with blank or non-blank media