# Unable to play DVDs on Ubuntu 22

Tags: video, vlc, dvd

How do you watch movie DVDs on Ubuntu 22?

When I install a commercial movie DVD into my player, nothing happens.

I've install Xine and VLC, and run through all the guides (mostly outdated ones like [this](https://itsfoss.com/play-dvd-ubuntu-1310/)) to install libdvdcss, making sure `/dev/dvd` exists, rebooting, the whole shebang.

Yet if I launch Xine and press "DVD", gives me the error:

```
There is no input plugin available to handle 'dvd:/'
```

And if I launch VLC, play, and select DVD at `/dev/sr0`, it gives me the error:

```
Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "/dev/sr0".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///dev/sr0'. Check the log for details.
```

Does anyone even still watching DVDs anymore, much less on Linux? Searching these errors, I can't find any help docs for anything later than 18.04. Most help docs are for versions even older than that, like [this almost identical question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302632/vlc-wont-run-dvds) for Ubuntu 13.

[This community page on playing DVDs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs) hasn't been updated version 15. None of the packages are available for Ubuntu 22, although similarly named ones are.

Is DVD playback on Linux essentially dead due to general lack of interest?

Comment: Are you sure you're not using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS? or 22.10? (ie. a *deb* based system that can also use *snap* packages), Ubuntu Core 22 is the *snap* only flavor of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server and is intended for *headless* operation only; 22 being a different product to 22.04.  FYI:  I installed a DVD in a system yesterday & it played  (*given how boring the movie was I suspect I'd have preferred if it didn't*)

Comment: Re-read that help.ubuntu.com wiki page. Review the section "Ubuntu 15.10 and newer" that you might have missed the first time, and which is still accurate.

Comment: @Nmath Yes. That's part of the instructions in my first link.

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Comment: @user535733 Yes, I know. Installing and configuring `libdvd-pkg` didn't work for me.

Comment: Ah, that was not clear from the question. One assumes you checked the logs as your output suggested, but that information is also missing from the question.

Comment: Please correct your question then, 22 & 22.04 are different products; 22 being a *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server

Comment: Try `xine dvd://dev/sr0`, `vlc dvd://dev/sr0` and `mpv dvd://dev/sr0`  in terminal and post what errors you see.